# DJIWaypointMissionHeadingTowardPointOfInterest, but the gimbal pitch angle?

Tags: dji-sdk

using DJIWaypointMissionHeadingTowardPointOfInterest as heading mode in DJIWaypointMission i can automatically rotate the drone to heading vs a POI, but is there a way to also automatically tilt the camera to frame the POI? 
(unlucky also the "pointOfInterest" have no altitude property)

also i think that would be better change/define the heading mode in the DJIWaypoint instead to be a property of the entire DJIWaypointMission, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding to what Ken said.
When you use 'isGimbalPitchRotationEnabled' you can set a pitch angle in each waypoint. The drone will change the pitch angle in a linear motion between each 2 waypoints.
Of course this will not work when during a flight between the 2 points the drone gets closer to the POI and than backs away.
What I'm doing in my app is dividing the straight line between the 2 points into several straight sections and calculating the correct pitch at each point. As I divide the original line I calculate the error (the difference between the calculated pitch and the linear extrapolated pitch). If the error is greater than some value (5 degrees, for example) I divide the line recursively and re-calculate the pitch, until the error at each point is small enough. It takes some geometric calculations when preparing the mission, but it produces amazing fly-by shots.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but your method require the "curvedPath" to avoid the drone to stop also on the "Extra waypoint" that you add to correct the gimbalpitch, so end user also can't define action on waypoint.. so many limitation, i was thinking that DJI firmwares were more flexible/intelligent, looks like i have to adapt my self and my project...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these settings:

isGimbalPitchRotationEnabled and gimbalPitch

This isn't a 'true' location though because the pitch divides equally based on the distance between the waypoints but it's close.

In my app I manually control the gimbal but that means a connection must be maintained or the gimbal stops moving.

Yes, it would be nice if the POI in waypoints was a true POI functionality and I've made the suggestion many times but to no avail so far.  I'd like to see the POI be a per waypoint (as a LocationCoordinate 3D) rather than the current, 1 POI for the whole mission.

I'd also like to see the location in waypoint to be consistent and be of type LocationCoordinate3D.